# Call Async method inside Rest API method not returns at all

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous, async-await

I need a function to be executed in the background after the request is completed.
My code is something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] List<JObject> lstData)
{
     return PostMethod(lstData);
}

 HttpResponseMessage PostMethod(List<JObject> lstData)
{
     //do somework
     Method1();
     return myResult;

}

void Method1()
{
     Method2();
}

async void Method2()
{
     //do some work
     await Task.Delay(25);
     Method2();
}
```

When this scenario run, Post doesn't return at all.
I was handling it by creating a task that executes Method2(), but I an trying to make use of the [Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: Is this your actual code? If `Method2` recursively calls itself, this should stackoverflow.

Comment: try using `PostMethod(lstData).Result`.

Comment: Yes, It is monitoring a list and processes its items whenever it has any. I'm using a delay to prevent stackoverflow.

Comment: Then when do you return a result? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: PostMethod is the one responsible to return the result. Method2 is the required background task.

Comment: It doesn't appear as though you have a full understanding of the request lifetime. You are attempting to basically kick off a sort of windows service-like method to keep running after your method has hit it's return and responded, which will not work. If you need something to happen in an async method and then return you can await it or use a continuation to return a response once it has finished.

Comment: I have a queue that multiple requests add items to it, and I need to generate one task to process all items in this list as they need to be processed sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

When using async-await it is really best to let the async-await syntax flow from top to bottom of your application. Also, do not ever return async void unless it is a front-end event handler, you want to at least return async Task. async void will cause you to have undesired side effects such as losing the current context, and current methods could end up deadlocked/blocked at those calls.

I suggest you re-write your method stack to async Task and async Task<.Type>, you will be in a much better place that way :).

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] List<JObject>     lstData)
{
  return await PostMethod(lstData);
}

async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostMethod(List<JObject> lstData)
{
 //do somework
 await Method1();
 return myResult;
}

async Task Method1()
{
   await Method2();
}

async Task Method2()
{
 //do some work
 await Task.Delay(25);
}
```

And follow this the whole method chain down.